# How to call/pass an array value from a table cell into a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

As novice/beginner programmer for iOS, I unfortunately have come across a roadblock that I would like some assistance with.  Using storyboards, I have created a table view that has a single prototype cell.  This cell then gets populated with information that has been passed from an array (two labels, titleLabel and timeLabel, as well as a "type" of cell that is represented by an integer, typeOfCell), allowing multiple cells to be generated by the array, while only using the single prototype cell "template".  **What I am trying to accomplish is to allow the user to select a cell from the table, and then have a view come up that displays the information in that cell.**  Since I am a beginner, please give explicit instructions should you choose to answer this question.  Any feedback is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0):

So if I get this correctly, you click on a cell in the table, you want to move to different view? That is what is the UINavigationController is supposed to do. Here is a link  [UINavigationController apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope this is what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at passing the values from the tablecell to the view that is called, then you can create member variables in the view corresponding to the values to be passed, synthesize it and pass the values in the `didSelectRow` method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       CustomTableCell *lCell = (CustomTableCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

       if(indexPath.row == x) //x being the row required 
       {
            NewViewController *lNewVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init]; //This class will have titleLabel, timeLabel and cellType as member vars
            lNewVC.titleLabel = cell.titleLabel;       
            lNewVC.timeLabel = cell.timeLabel;
            lNewVC.cellType = cell.typeOfCell;

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:lNewVC animated:YES];
       }
       else
       /* similar code for other rows */
   }
```